# The usage of Docker base images of Azure Functions

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

I'm new to both Docker and Azure Functions so it must be a silly question...

You can pull the images of Azure Functions from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-functions-node), like:

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node12
```

Now I pulled the image of a specific runtime of Azure Functions, but what can I do with this exactly?

First I thought I could find **Azure Functions Core Tools** inside of the container, then found the **azure-function-host** directory with bunch of files, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
docker exec -it "TheContainerMadeOfAzureFunctionsImage" bash

-> FuncExtensionBundles  azure-functions-host  bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I guess you are supossed to put your function code in the image. Then you can deploy the image to azure and run it as functions thing. The link you posted contains also a link to some in depth tutorial. Maybe follow this along one time from top to bottom. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-linux-custom-image?tabs=bash%2Cportal&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: @TheFool thank you for a comment and you guessed it right. In fact I already tried it. In the tutorial there is no `docker pull` but the image can be built, and I assume that's because Dockerfile holds lines like `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0`. I wonder, if I have the MS-provided image of Azure Functions pulled on my local machine, what is a good thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the [remote development extension tools for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack) and the [Azure Functions extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions).

Create your local folder then using the remote development tools, open that folder inside a container from the command pallette by selecting 'Reopen In Container'

[Reopen In Container Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBqGR.png)

Then select your definition.

[Remote Dev Tools Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ovep.png)

This actually use those base images you mentioned.

It will create a `.devcontainer` hidden directory in your repo where it stores the container information and saves you having to install the Function Core tools/NPM or anything else on your local machine.

It automatically forwards the required ports for local debugging and you can push the devcontainer definitions to source control so that others can use your definition with the project.

Comment: sorry for late reply but the instructions you shared was really useful, so I accepted it. Thank you so much Brett!

Answer (score 0):

Last week I solved it myself. I found the exact image in Docker Hub, then `docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node12-core-tools` and that's it.

[You can find a full list of available tags for each runtime.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0Ub.png)

In container you can run both Azure Functions Core Tools and a language runtime (like Node.js or Python, etc.) and of course you can create function apps.

With port-forwarding like `docker run -it -p 8080:7071 --name container1 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:3.0-node12-core-tools bash` you can debug your functions running inside a container (which uses port 7071) from your local machine, by sending HTTP requests to localhost:8080. This is somewhat brute force but I'm happy.